# how to access image in xml file with linq to xml

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

In my project i am accessing xml file data with linq, xml file containing images in binary format.

I want to read that xml file and assign that image in xml file to picturebox on my form.

However I am not able to do that: while i am applying queries on xml file it is not understanding datatype for any element...

What is the problem?

This is my sample xml file & code in c#::

```xml
/////////xml file agency.xml////////////
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="agency">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="no" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Slogan" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Vatno." type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="MainBranch" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Disclaimer" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Logo" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="town_x002F_city" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="State_x002F_Country" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PostalCode" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Phone1" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Phone2" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Fax" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Emailid" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Website" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <agency>
    <no>1</no>
    <Name>Good Deal Pvt</Name>
    <Slogan>We Values of Your Money</Slogan>
    <Vatno.>123</Vatno.>
    <MainBranch>Your Branch One</MainBranch>
    <Disclaimer>All the information is legal still the buyer should collect other details if needed. This intended to give          information &amp;   not part of any agreement.</Disclaimer>
    <Logo>here is actually that lengthy binary data for image, i have edit that </Logo>
    <street>Link Raod, Near Satara Road,Pune</street>
    <town_x002F_city>Pune</town_x002F_city>
    <State_x002F_Country>Mahrastra</State_x002F_Country>
    <PostalCode>231231</PostalCode>
    <Phone1>1231313</Phone1>
    <Phone2>12312323</Phone2>
    <Fax>1231231</Fax>
    <Emailid>Gooddeal@gmail.com</Emailid>
    <Website>www.gooddeal.com</Website>
  </agency>
</NewDataSet>
```

```cs
////////sample code c# code to access above xml file//////////
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("c:\\xml1\\agency.xml");
var result = from agen in doc.Descendants("agency")
where  (int)agen.Element("no") == 1
select// agen;
new
{
      no = (string)agen.Element("no"),
      Name =(string) agen.Element("Name"),
      Slogan = (string)agen.Element("Slogan"),
      logo =  agen.Element("Logo")
 };

 foreach (var tuple in result)
 {
   textbox1.text=tuple.Name;
   textbox2.text=tuple.Slogan;

   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tuple.logo.ToString()));
   Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap(ms);
   this.pictureBox1.Image = bmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When image data or byte array serializa into XML it is basically base64 encoded data.

You have to first convert base64 to byte array.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx

Then load that data into memory stream.

then ms.Location = 0 ( memory stream starting location)

Than use in bitmap .

Thanks.